# Why the currently running virtualbox vm is not shown as running?

Tags: virtualbox

Whilst I was running the following command to find out which process blocks my postgresql port:

```
sudo netstat -tnlp
```

I got the following record:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10986/VBoxHeadless
```

Hence, I run the following command:

```
ps 10986
```

That resulted:

```
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
10986 ?        Sl     7:00 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment etable-databases --startvm dbabe55
```

But once I run the command:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

I get an empty list. Do you know why I am unable to list the running vm that `ps` command had shown to me?

I mean if it binds the port, the vm should be running, using a database tool such as bdeaver, I am able to connect to the vm as well, but still I am unable to get listed into `runningvms` also the gui does not show this particular vm running as well.

The problem was solved by soflty terminating the process:

```
sudo kill -15 10986
```

And removing any folders related to the vm:

```
sudo rm -rf "~/Virtualbox Vms/etable-databases"
```

Also, the vm represented a vagrant box for my dev environment, henve I needed to re-create the vagrant:

```
vagrant destroy && vagrant up
```

But still I still have the bad taste on my mouth on how this could happen. Why the `VBoxManage` cli was unable to locate the vm?

I am using Virtualbox `5.2.42` on Ubuntu Mate Edition 18.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

`VBoxManage list runningvms` shows only VMs running under the current user account.

Comment: So you imply that the VM was running under another user?

Comment: Yes, I do. In fact I've verified that.